# swift Convert dictionary to jsonString error : Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Encodable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols

Tags: ios, json, swift, encode

I have a dictionary and I want to convert to jsonstring.

> Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Encodable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols
>   How to fix it? Thanks.

```
func save(body: [String: Any]) -> Void {

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(body) { //error here.
        if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(jsonString)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `JSONSerialization` instead. But Dictionary and JSONEncoder? Don't you use Codable?

Comment: Please read the error message carefully. It's pretty clear and means exactly what it says.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the body type something that conforms to `Codable`. To fix this issue create another `struct` that conforms to `Codable` and change the type of `body` variable to it.

Here's an example:

```swift
struct Body: Codable { 
// all the properties you require can be added here.
}

func save(body: Body) -> Void {

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(body) {
        if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(jsonString)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use JSONSerialisation like this:

```swift
func save(body: [String: Any]) -> Void {

    if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .prettyPrinted) {
        if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(jsonString)
        }
    }
}
```